# Función concat() para sustituira frame.append method

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, conda

Con el código siguiente, importamos de [https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBEX_35](https://url%20=%20%27https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBEX_35%27)

en un DataFrame, una tabla con las siguientes características de cotizaciones del 'IBEX 25'. (['Ticker', 'Empresa', 'Sede', 'Entrada', 'Sector19', 'ISIN',
'PonderacinSep2022'])

```
import pandas as pd

# Especifica la URL de la página que contiene la tabla
url = 'https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBEX_35'

# Utiliza la función read_html() para importar todas las tablas de la página
tablas = pd.read_html(url)

# La tabla que deseas importar es la tercera en la página
tabla_ibex35 = tablas[3]

# Ahora tenemos la tabla en un DataFrame llamado 'tabla_ibex35'
# Podemos trabajar con ella como lo haríamos con cualquier otro DataFrame de pandas

tabla_ibex35.columns = tabla_ibex35.columns.str.replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', regex=True)

tabla_ibex35.columns
```

Posteriormente el código nos preguntará el número de valores que queremos seleccionar, nos permite elegirlos y añadir las caracetrísticas seleccionadas de los valores elegidos en un nuevo DataFraame.

```
import pandas as pd

# 1. Pedir el número de empresas que quieres seleccionar
num_empresas = int(input("¿Cuántas empresas desea seleccionar? "))

# Crear un DataFrame para almacenar las empresas seleccionadas
empresas_seleccionadas_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Ticker', 'Empresa', 'ISIN'])

# 2. Presentar y permitir seleccionar un sector para la primera empresa
print("Sectores disponibles:")
sectores_disponibles = tabla_ibex35['Sector19'].unique()
for idx, sector in enumerate(sectores_disponibles, start=1):
    print(f"{idx}. {sector}")

sector_elegido_idx = int(input("Elija un sector para la primera empresa (ingrese el número correspondiente): "))
sector_elegido = sectores_disponibles[sector_elegido_idx - 1]

# 3. Elegir una empresa del sector elegido y repetir para cada empresa
for i in range(num_empresas):
    while True:  # Bucle para manejar selecciones inválidas
        print(f"Empresas en el sector '{sector_elegido}':")
        empresas_sector = tabla_ibex35[tabla_ibex35['Sector19'] == sector_elegido]

        if empresas_sector.empty:
            print(f"No se encontraron empresas en el sector '{sector_elegido}'.")
            break

        # Presentar empresas con índice iniciando en 1
        for idx, empresa in enumerate(empresas_sector['Empresa'], start=1):
            print(f"{idx}. {empresa}")

        empresa_elegida_idx = int(input(f"Elija una empresa del sector '{sector_elegido}' (ingrese el número correspondiente): "))

        if 1 <= empresa_elegida_idx <= len(empresas_sector):
            empresa_elegida = empresas_sector.iloc[empresa_elegida_idx - 1]
            empresas_seleccionadas_df = empresas_seleccionadas_df.append(empresa_elegida[['Ticker', 'Empresa', 'ISIN']])
            empresas_seleccionadas_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)  # Restablecer el índice
            print(f"Empresa '{empresa_elegida['Empresa']}' seleccionada.")
            break
        else:
            print("Selección inválida. Por favor, elija un número válido.")

    # Presentar y permitir seleccionar otro sector para la próxima empresa (si es necesario)
    if i < num_empresas - 1:
        print("\nSectores disponibles:")
        for idx, sector in enumerate(sectores_disponibles, start=1):
            print(f"{idx}. {sector}")

        sector_elegido_idx = int(input("Elija un sector para la próxima empresa (ingrese el número correspondiente): "))
        sector_elegido = sectores_disponibles[sector_elegido_idx - 1]

# 4. Mostrar las empresas seleccionadas
print("Empresas seleccionadas:")
print(empresas_seleccionadas_df)
```

Nos devuelve

```
Empresa 'Acciona' seleccionada.
Empresas seleccionadas:
  Ticker  Empresa          ISIN
0    ANA  Acciona  ES0125220311
1    ANA  Acciona  ES0125220311

/tmp/ipykernel_20483/40746630.py:38: FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
  empresas_seleccionadas_df = empresas_seleccionadas_df.append(empresa_elegida[['Ticker', 'Empresa', 'ISIN']])
```

Para evitar la advertencia, Implementamos 'concat', sustituyendo a 'append'.

```
import pandas as pd

# Supongamos que ya tienes el DataFrame 'tabla_ibex35' con los datos importados desde la página web.

# 1. Pedir el número de empresas que quieres seleccionar
num_empresas = int(input("¿Cuántas empresas desea seleccionar? "))

# Crear un DataFrame para almacenar las empresas seleccionadas
empresas_seleccionadas_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Ticker', 'Empresa', 'ISIN'])

# 2. Presentar y permitir seleccionar un sector para la primera empresa
print("Sectores disponibles:")
sectores_disponibles = tabla_ibex35['Sector19'].unique()
for idx, sector in enumerate(sectores_disponibles, start=1):
    print(f"{idx}. {sector}")

sector_elegido_idx = int(input("Elija un sector para la primera empresa (ingrese el número correspondiente): "))
sector_elegido = sectores_disponibles[sector_elegido_idx - 1]

# 3. Elegir una empresa del sector elegido y repetir para cada empresa
for i in range(num_empresas):
    while True:  # Bucle para manejar selecciones inválidas
        print(f"Empresas en el sector '{sector_elegido}':")
        empresas_sector = tabla_ibex35[tabla_ibex35['Sector19'] == sector_elegido]

        if empresas_sector.empty:
            print(f"No se encontraron empresas en el sector '{sector_elegido}'.")
            break

        # Presentar empresas con índice iniciando en 1
        for idx, empresa in enumerate(empresas_sector['Empresa'], start=1):
            print(f"{idx}. {empresa}")

        empresa_elegida_idx = int(input(f"Elija una empresa del sector '{sector_elegido}' (ingrese el número correspondiente): "))

        if 1 <= empresa_elegida_idx <= len(empresas_sector):
            empresa_elegida = empresas_sector.iloc[empresa_elegida_idx - 1]
            empresas_seleccionadas_df = pd.concat([empresas_seleccionadas_df, empresa_elegida[['Ticker', 'Empresa', 'ISIN']]], ignore_index=True)
            print(f"Empresa '{empresa_elegida['Empresa']}' seleccionada.")
            break
        else:
            print("Selección inválida. Por favor, elija un número válido.")

    # Presentar y permitir seleccionar otro sector para la próxima empresa (si es necesario)
    if i < num_empresas - 1:
        print("\nSectores disponibles:")
        for idx, sector in enumerate(sectores_disponibles, start=1):
            print(f"{idx}. {sector}")

        sector_elegido_idx = int(input("Elija un sector para la próxima empresa (ingrese el número correspondiente): "))
        sector_elegido = sectores_disponibles[sector_elegido_idx - 1]

# 4. Mostrar las empresas seleccionadas
print("Empresas seleccionadas:")
print(empresas_seleccionadas_df)
```

que nos devuelve.

```
Empresa 'Acciona' seleccionada.
Empresas seleccionadas:

    Ticker  Empresa     ISIN    0
0   NaN     NaN     NaN     ANA
1   NaN     NaN     NaN     Acciona
2   NaN     NaN     NaN     ES0125220311
3   NaN     NaN     NaN     ANA
4   NaN     NaN     NaN     Acciona
5   NaN     NaN     NaN     ES0125220311
```

¿Cuál es la causa y cómo puedo solucionar este error?.